# How can I import Excel file columns in Python and find correlation coefficient between them?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have a lot of columns of numbers (for example, AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD and EEE) in Excel file.
I need to import these columns into Python and find correlation coefficient between every 2 columns.
Only show columns which have correlation coefficient from +0.5 to +1 and -0.5 to -1.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('SO.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.corr()
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you show us what you've tried so far?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: If you wanted to break this down into two parts - I would say use the pandas library to import your data, and then there is a very useful article here which tells you how to use numpy to calculate correlation: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-correlation-to-understand-the-relationship-between-variables/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really simple solution to this issue; I don't have your data so I've done it with sample data I found.  Here we go:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780199734177/Example_1_rawdata.xls')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.corr()
```

The output looks like this:

```
              Hugs       Comps       PerAd       SocAc       ProAd        ComSt       PhyHlp    Encour       Tutor
    Hugs    1.000000    0.666100    0.149995    0.616721    0.541132    0.653129    0.473344    0.549393    0.565627
    Comps   0.666100    1.000000    0.247194    0.575720    0.509667    0.642069    0.424696    0.543826    0.487571
    PerAd   0.149995    0.247194    1.000000    0.222337    0.081263    0.163510    0.090505    0.181000    0.120080
    SocAc   0.616721    0.575720    0.222337    1.000000    0.409031    0.559579    0.338293    0.447923    0.348733
    ProAd   0.541132    0.509667    0.081263    0.409031    1.000000    0.666905    0.733851    0.464976    0.754339
    ComSt   0.653129    0.642069    0.163510    0.559579    0.666905    1.000000    0.595900    0.540038    0.671789
    PhyHlp  0.473344    0.424696    0.090505    0.338293    0.733851    0.595900    1.000000    0.432037    0.717585
    Encour  0.549393    0.543826    0.181000    0.447923    0.464976    0.540038    0.432037    1.000000    0.412042
    Tutor   0.565627    0.487571    0.120080    0.348733    0.754339    0.671789    0.717585    0.412042    1.000000
```

If you add the following it will replace all the the values with a Pearson correlation below 0.5 with nulls:

```
df[df > 0.5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Plato77, I will have to work it out and revert back on this.

Comment: How could I add the "df[df > 0.5]" and "df[df < -0.5]" into the code to show only correlation coefficients from +0.5 to +1 and -0.5 to -1?